# Unable to delete product exported .CSV files in Magento 2 from admin panel

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I am trying to delete .csv files from the admin panel but unable to delete. I have added screenshot below. I'm using Magento 2.4.7-beta2. Is there any other way for delete this file ?

[image]
[screenshot](https://prnt.sc/lrXgc7hoaAZp)

Please suggest.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File Permissions:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/magento
```

Magento Cache:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: @Sumit is it possible .csv file delete from admin side ?

Comment: @Gaurav yes, all the exported files from the Magento admin panel can be removed from the export section.

Comment: @Sumit, yes it's working. i have delete file from admin side. **chown -R www-data:www-data magento247b2/**  thanks for help me

Answer (score 0):

You can delete them via ssh. They are located under the var/imports folder. From the root of your magneto folder execute rm var/imports/*.csv

Comment: is it possible .csv file delete from admin side ?

Comment: Magento does not have a delete option in the admin panel by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can review the system/debug logs in the var directory during the delete action. Based on the error, you can implement/find the solution. For example, if there is a permission issue (file access issue), then you can update the file permissions.

**Permission Command:**

```
chmod -R 777 var/import/
```

**Another Solution:**

If you have the server access then you can login to SSH & try below command:

```
rm -rf var/import/filename
```

If you are already connected to the FTP, you can remove the file from the same directory.

Comment: is it possible .csv file delete from admin side ?

Comment: Hi @Gaurav, Magento already provided you an option to the same page to remove the files. But there might be the permission issues that is why you were unable to delete it from the admin.

Comment: So you have to provide the correct permissions to the files via SSH.